# AWS Lamdba nodejs12.x error `args[3]->IsInt32()' failed

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, prisma

I would require some inputs to understand the AWS Lamdba serverless functionality. I had deployed node.js +prisma +graphql code in AWS Lambda and it worked fine till today morning. Suddenly,the Graphql API calls started failing with the below error.

/var/lang/bin/node[9]: ../src/node_http_parser_impl.h:529:static void node::{anonymous}::Parser::Initialize(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args[3]->IsInt32()' failed.
1: 0x564c9d50b1a3 node::Abort() [/var/lang/bin/node]
5: 0x564c9d72fde1 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/var/lang/bin/node]
RequestId: 760c0979-cab3-4118-aadf-81d9776e2cb9 Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: aborted (core dumped)Runtime.ExitError

Investigated  and found that I would need either upgrade prisma version to 2.9.0 or upgrade my node.js. Reference link: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35582.
I haven't made any new deployment for the last few days so don't understand why suddenly this error is appearing.

Two questions that I am unable to understand:

1. Why did the error occur today when I haven't deployed any new code for the last few days in AWS.
2. It is possible to understand which version of Node.js used in AWS ? It says runtime: nodejs12.x .. is it 12.9.0 ? Because the error as per link below occurs only because of 12.9.0. Did AWS upgrade their node.js version recently ?

Thanks for your help.

P.S: I upgraded my prisma to 2.11.0 to resolve the problem however I can't understand what happened to cause the error suddenly in the first place. Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: There was an error due to the `undcii` dependency of Node that had functionality changed in version 12.9.0 which Prisma depended on. Which is why we needed to release a new version with the fix and support for Node 12.9.0+

Comment: Hi Ryan ! Thank you. I understand the dependency issue however the issue surfaced in AWS suddenly which means something would have changed in AWS side which triggered it. I cant find any info on the same. Any idea why AWS stopped working suddenly ?

Comment: It's due to AWS updating their NodeJS version from `12.8.4` to `12.9.0`. In AWS Lambda, you cannot specify the exact version of Node to run, you can only specify the major version like `12.x`. Which is why this error occured.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Does AWS provide a timeline when they upgrade these version ? This upgrade activity caught my team by surprise so wondering whether they publish this timeline so we can test against the correct version locally before we see the problem. Niv